# Time stamp conversion to seconds

Tags: matlab, timestamp, type-conversion, unix-timestamp

I have time stamp 7.351173057570145e+05 which should represent '05-Sep-2012 14:20:17'. Unfortunately I do not know which timeformat that is.

If I use timestr() in Matlab, I get '05-Sep-2012 07:20:17'. Apparently my time is of 7 hours (consistently for all files). 
I tried to add 7*3600 seconds to the timestamp, as I thought it is seconds from 1970, but that is just wrong. 
If I subtract the times I get a difference of 0.2915. This means 7 hours is represented as 0.2915. I do not understand how this works.

1. What time format is that?
2. Is there method to add x hours to the time?
3. Is there a method to convert that into unix time (in- or excluding ms)?

Thanks you for your help.

Comment: 7/24 = 0.291667

Comment: That makes sense. Do you know the name of that timestamp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation of [`timestr`](http://mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4299-timestr?focused=6778267&tab=function) mentions that it expects the format returned by `dateenum`:

> TS = TIMESTR(D) converts D, a serial date number (**as returned by
>   DATENUM**) into string TS with the format HH:MM:SS.SSSS.

[`dateenum`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html#btfl6he-4) returns the number of days since January 0, 0000:

> The datenum function creates a numeric array that represents each
>   point in time as **the number of days from January 0, 0000**.

So, if your offset is 7 hours, the difference should be 7/24, which is indeed 0.2917 as suggested by L. Scott Johnson.

From 2014b, you can use [`datetime`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.html) to manipulate datetimes:

```
v = 7.351173057570145e+05;

d = datetime(v, 'ConvertFrom', 'datenum');
d.Hour = d.Hour + 7; % correct for the offset
d_posix = posixtime(d); % converts to posix
```

Comment: You can also use `datenum(0,0,0,7,0,0)` to produce the offset, which possibly better describes your intent.  Could 7 hours be a timezone thing?  UTC vs. local time perhaps?  If you're on a recent MATLAB, the new `datetime` facility provides more complete handling of dates and times, including timezones.

Comment: Thanks for your help. That did the trick. I was already wondering about the timezone. Interestingly the data was recorded in the Netherlands, which is +1. Probably the recording software is from the Midwest US.

Comment: Done, I just checked it first and compared the answers.

Answer (score 2):

You can first convert your [date number](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html) (which represents time as the number of days from January 0, 0000) to a [`datetime`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.html) object to make it a little easier to work with:

```
>> num = 7.351173057570145e+05;
>> dt = datetime(num, 'ConvertFrom', 'datenum')
dt = 
  datetime
   05-Sep-2012 07:20:17
```

You can then easily modify it using the [`hours`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hours.html) function to add 7 hours like so:

```
>> dt = dt+hours(7)
dt = 
  datetime
   05-Sep-2012 14:20:17
```

You can then convert it to [UNIX time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) (i.e. the number of seconds, including fractional seconds, elapsed since 00:00:00 1-Jan-1970 UTC (Universal Coordinated Time), ignoring leap seconds) using the function [`posixtime`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/posixtime.html):

```
>> format long
>> pt = posixtime(dt)
pt =
     1.346854817406057e+09
```

**NOTE:** The fact that your time stamp is off by 7 hours from what you were expecting might be a time zone issue, as mentioned in [a comment by Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44158808/time-stamp-conversion-to-seconds/44160056#comment75336161_44159549). You may be able to account for this by passing some extra arguments to `datetime` when you convert the date number. Specifically, you should check out the [`'TimeZone'`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.html#input_argument_d0e189029) argument.

Comment: Dear gnovice, thanks  for your answer. That helped a lot. Nevertheless, the +hours apparently change the variable into a "duration" which is not accepted by posixtime. Anyways, it gave me the right idea. As mentioned above I also think it is a timezone problem.

Comment: @FloridaMan: Are you sure of that? It should still be a datetime, not a duration. What version are you running?

Comment: ... that is something. I rechecked and you are right. I do not know what I did the first time. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

to quickly answer your questions:

1. it is like @gnovice pointed out of the format 'datenum', which is
   the number of days since 0-Jan-0000
2. just add to your number x/24
3. you can transfer it to normal time, then back to unix time.